# Can Soundflower route audio into Facetime?

Tags: audio, facetime, soundflower

I have successfully routed my built-in microphone's audio to a Google Hangout through [AU Lab](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/) via [Soundflower](https://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/), and want to do the same with Facetime. Using the same settings as with the Google Hangout seem to be unsuccessful. The setup for Hangouts is as follows:

- AU Lab document with Built-in Microphone being routed to 'Soundflower 2ch'
- In Google Hangout settings, setting the "Microphone" field to 'Soundflower 2ch'
- In System Preferences, setting Output tab to the default (Headphones / Built-in Output).

This does the trick for Hangouts, but Facetime doesn't appear to be picking up audio from Soundflower. Would there be a reason for this? Does Facetime not interact with system audio in the same way?

I am on the Mid-2014 model MBP with OSX 9.4, Soundflower 1.6.6, AU Lab 2.2.2, and the most recent Facetime.

Comment: Anyone have an update on this?  I have a 3 mic setup with soundflower and logic pro, and the phone call works just fine with the `facetime` app routing out the sound to `SoundFlower (2ch)` but as the same issue above, the computer sound that is routed thru SF doesnot push other sounds to the phone call.